# Cómo convierto un string JSON a objeto Java

Tags: php, java, json, parsear

Tengo un string que me guarda un JSON con la información de una consulta SQL que me devuelve un archivo.php

Bueno necesito saber cómo puedo convertir esa información a un objeto en Java apartir de ese string.

Dejo adjunto una imagen con mi código por si necesitan verlo.

Un saludo y gracias desde ya.

Comment: echale un ojo a esta publicación https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688099/converting-json-data-to-java-object

Comment: *Dejo adjunto una imagen con mi código por si necesitan verlo.*  ... La imagen no se ve. De todos modos, en lugar de la imagen publica el texto del código debidamente identado. Sólo tienes que pegarlo, seleccionarlo todo y pulsar sobre el símbolo **`{ }`** en la barra superior que aparece cuando editas.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar JSONObject y JSONArray.Por ejemplo:

```
//stringJson es el string que obtienes del php
String stringJson;
JSONObject jsonobject;
JSONArray jsonarray;

String usuario,contrasena;


jsonobject=new JSONObject(stringJson);
int cont=0;
//respuesta_servidor es el nombre del array que tiene en el php
jsonarray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("respuesta_servidor");
while(count<jsonarray.length()){
 JSONObject jo= jsonarray.getJSONObject(count);
 usuario=jo.getString("user");
 contrasena=jo.getString("passwd");

Usuario usuario=new Usuario(usuario,contrasena);
count++
}
```

Y ya es decisión tuya lo que quieras hacer con cada objeto, yo los metería dentro de un arraylist, pero eso ya como veas tu.